# optimizing usage of bookshelf with graphql-bookshelf

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, graphql-js

I have created a small example where the model is like the following

```
Student --- hasMany ---> Homework --- hasMany -----> Page
```

Now, when I load the following (note: viewer is the student) the there is one query for the student, one for the homework, but multiple for the pages. There are as many queries as there are pages. How can i optimize it so that there is only one query for the all the pages.

Best case scenario would be to load the whole thing at once, but i'd be happy for any pointers on how to optimize this.

```
{ 
 viewer(id: 3) {
    name
    homeworks{
      subject
      pages{
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code I've used to test this is available at https://gist.github.com/hardfire/3ff69d3a602bf3c30dcbbca71d67d605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've learned in the past days, It's not possible to do this just with bookshelf and graphql's philosophy doesn't allow something like this.

The best option is to use [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader). Using it with bookshelf should be straight forward. I'll have to play with it to figure out the best pattern to use it.

An example loader for the Page would be something like

```js
var PageLoader = new Dataloader(keys => {
 return Page
  .where('homework_id', 'IN', keys)
  .fetchAll()
  .then(collection => {
    var groupedItems = _.groupBy(collection.models, (el) => el.get('homework_id'))
    return _.map(keys, key => groupedItems[key])
  })
})
```

This can then be used as following in the HomeworkType

```js
...
pages: {
  type: new GraphQLList(PageType),
  description: 'pages in the homework',
  resolve: (homework) => PageLoader.load(homework.id)
},
...
```